# Problem from the book Measure Theory by Paul Halmos

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

If $\{E_n\}$ is a sequence of sets, write

$D_1=E_1, D_2=D_1 \triangle E_2, D_3=D_2 \triangle E_3$

and, in general,

$D_{n+1}=D_n \triangle E_{n+1}$

Prove that the limit of the sequence $\{D_n\}$ exists if and only if $\lim_n E_n=\emptyset$.

My Attempt: Suppose that the limit of the sequence $\{D_n\}$ exists. Then we have to first show that the $\lim E_n$ exists and is equal to $\emptyset.$ For the first part, we have to show that $\lim \sup E_n=\lim \inf E_n.$ Let $x\in \lim\sup E_n$ then we have that there exists a subsequence $\{E_{n_k}\}$ of sets that each contain $x.$ Look at $D_{n_1}=D_{n_1-1}\triangle E_{n_1}$, then $x\in D_{n_1}$ because $x\in E_{n_1}$ and if were in $x\in D_{n_1-1}$ then it would have to be in $D_{n_1-2},D_{n_1-3},...,D_{1}=E_1$ which is not true if $n_1>1.$ So we have that $x\in D_{n_1}.$  Look at $D_{n_2}=D_{n_2-1}\triangle E_{n_2}$ then clearly $x\not \in D_{n_2}.$ Thus $x\in D_{n_k}$ for odd $k$ and $x\not \in D_{n_k}$ for even $k.$ Hence we have that $x\in \lim\sup D_n$ and so $x\not \in \lim \inf D_n$ because the limit of the sequence $D_n$ exists. But this is contradiction since $\lim \sup D_n=\lim \inf D_n.$ So such an $x$ does not exist so $\lim \sup E_n=\emptyset.$

If $x\in \lim \inf E_n$ then after a finite number $n$ we have that $x\in E_k$ for all $k\geq n.$ Look at $D_{k}=D_{k-1}\triangle E_k.$ Then $x\in D_k,D_{k+2},D_{k+4}...$ whereas $x\not \in D_{k+1},D_{k+3},D_{k+5},...$ Thus we again have that $x\in \lim \sup D_n$ and $x\not \in \lim \inf D_n$ which again implies that $\lim \inf E_n=\phi. $ Hence $\lim E_n$ exists and is equal to $\phi.$

Is this correct?

**Edit:**

Proof of the converse: I am not sure whether this is correct so please do give feedback wherever possible.

If $\lim E_n=\phi$ then we have to show that the limit of the sequence $\{D_n\}$ sequence exists, which means that we have to show that $\lim \sup D_n=\lim \inf D_n.$ Thus we start with $x\in \lim \sup D_n.$ Then there exists a subsequence $\{D_{n_k}\}$ which contains $x.$ Consider $D_{n_1}=D_{n_1-1}\triangle E_{n_1}$ then clearly $x\in E_{n_1}.$ Similarily if we have $D_{n_1+1}=D_{n_1}\triangle E_{n_1+1}$ then $x\in D_{n_1}$ but it is not in $D_{n_1+1}$ and so it must be the case that $x\in E_{n_1+1}.$ Now look at $D_{n_2}=D_{n_2-1}\triangle E_{n_2}.$ Here $x\in E_{n_2}$ and by the previous argument $x\in E_{n_2+1}.$ Thus we get that $x\in E_{n_1},E_{n_1+1},E_{n_2},E_{n_2+1},....$ Thus $x\in \lim \sup E_n$ which we know is empty thus we have that such an $x$ does not exist

PS(1) I have already read the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717855/halmos-measure-theory-exercise-on-limit-of-sequence-of-sets?answertab=active#tab-top), but I would be grateful if someone could verify the proof for me.

PS(2) I know that I have to prove the converse. I will add that in an edit.

Comment: One small comment, you don't need to show that $\lim \inf E_n=\varnothing$. It is always the case that $\lim \inf E_n$ is a subset of $\lim \sup E_n$. Thus, by showing that $\lim \sup E_n=\varnothing$, you can conclude immediately that $\lim \inf E_n=\varnothing$. More generally, this means that to establish a limit $\lim A_n$ exists it is sufficient to show that $$\lim \sup A_n\subseteq \lim \inf A_n.$$

Comment: Yeah you are right! I should have though about that. Otherwise do you think that I am on the right track?